# Incorrect route for DELETE method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, restful-url

For some reason `slide_path` gives me `/slides/1.1` for DELETE method rather than `/albums/1/slides/1`. Thanks in advance for any advice why it happens or/and how to solve it.

**my spec fail:**

```
 1) Slide Pages Delete slide
     Failure/Error: expect{page.find('.btn.btn-mini.btn-danger').click}.to change(Slide, :count).by(-1)
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [DELETE] "/slides/1.1"
     # ./spec/features/slides_spec.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/slides_spec.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**spec:**

```
 scenario "Delete slide" do
    visit album_slides_url slide.album
    expect{page.find('.btn.btn-mini.btn-danger').click}.to change(Slide, :count).by(-1)
  end
```

**view:**

```
    <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
    slide_path(slide.album.id, slide.id),
    :method => :delete,
    :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger',
    :remote => true %>
```

**rake routes:**

```
  slide GET      /slides/:id(.:format)                                             slides#show
        PATCH    /slides/:id(.:format)                                             slides#update
        PUT      /slides/:id(.:format)                                             slides#update
        DELETE   /albums/:album_id/slides/:ids(.:format)                           slides#destroy # this is the one I expect to get
        PATCH    /albums/:album_id/slides/:ids/dest_album/:dest_album_id(.:format) slides#move
        PUT      /albums/:album_id/slides/:ids/dest_album/:dest_album_id(.:format) slides#move
```

**routes.rb**:

```
  resources :albums, except: :show do
    resources :slides, shallow: true, except: [:destroy, :patch, :put]    
    match 'slides/:ids', to: 'slides#destroy', via: :delete
    match 'slides/:ids/dest_album/:dest_album_id', to: 'slides#move', via: :patch
    match 'slides/:ids/dest_album/:dest_album_id', to: 'slides#move', via: :put
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your defined routes, the `DELETE` route is NOT a named route, so when you say `slide_path(slide.album.id, slide.id)` in your link, rails routes would automatically try to match it with the listed routes prefixed with `slide` and with `DELETE` request.

To route the Delete Slide link properly to the DELETE route, you would need to update the routes as below:

```
resources :albums, except: :show do
  resources :slides, shallow: true, except: [:destroy, :patch, :put]    
  match 'slides/:ids', to: 'slides#destroy', via: :delete, as: :slide ## Note as option
  match 'slides/:ids/dest_album/:dest_album_id', to: 'slides#move', via: :patch
  match 'slides/:ids/dest_album/:dest_album_id', to: 'slides#move', via: :put
end
```

This will create the `DELETE` named route as below:

```
album_slide DELETE /albums/:album_id/slides/:ids(.:format)  slides#destroy
```

Now, update the Delete Slide link to map to this route:

```
<%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
    album_slide_path(slide.album.id, slide.id),
    :method => :delete,
    :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger',
    :remote => true %>
```

**UPDATE**

Your route was NOT a named route. As per your currently defined routes `slide_path` is only available for the following routes:

```
  slide GET      /slides/:id(.:format)                                             slides#show
        PATCH    /slides/:id(.:format)                                             slides#update
        PUT      /slides/:id(.:format)
```

which were created with   `resources :slides, shallow: true, except: [:destroy, :patch, :put]`

So, when you called `slide_path(slide.album.id, slide.id)` with two arguments, rails router tried to convert it into a path

```
/slides/:id(.:format)
```

so you received a request with path

```
slides/1.1 
       ^ ^
       a b
```

where

`a` => refers to `:id` dynamic segment of the slide_path route and value of `slide.album.id` was set to it

`b` => refers to `(.:format)` part of the slide_path route and value of `slide.id` was set to it. Format refers to the extension (.html, .json, etc) so you received `.1` in the path as `slide.id` was treated as `format`

Comment: Does it mean that creating routes with different `URI Pattern`'s for different `Verb`'s but the same `Prefix` (as `rake routes` names the collumns) is always incorrect ?

Comment: Read the `UPDATE` section in my answer.

Comment: yeye, I fully understand why it worked that way but what I'm asking now is if there is a situation where it's ok to create more different URI patterns for one named route ? In other words if it's true that 'if you want to have different URIs than you **always** have to use different named routes' or not?

Comment: Yes..that's true. You can't do that if you are going away from `Rails ways`. Only if you use rails RESTful routes i.e., created using `resources :slides`, Rails would give you the same prefix for different Verbs. For eg: slide_path for "GET, PATCH, PUT and DELETE"